# How to secure .NET API with Azure

Tags: .net, azure, jwt

I'm using .NET 5 and Azure to build an API that needs to be secured using JWT tokens. I've created an Azure app in the Azure portal and configured it to use JWT tokens, but I'm having trouble understanding how to actually implement token-based authentication in my API.

My goal is to have a /token endpoint in my API that takes different scopes and then uses those scopes to get a JWT token from the Azure token endpoint. I would then use that JWT token to authorize calls to my other endpoints.

Here's the code I have so far for my /token endpoint:

```
public class TokenController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<string>> GetToken([FromBody] TokenRequest request)
    {
        // TODO: Get JWT token from Azure and return it
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me understand how to get a JWT token from Azure and use it to secure my API?"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using App Service, you can go to Authentication menu, and setup the IDP (identity provider).

I usually use Azure AD, this way only users from your Azure AD will be able to acquire the JWT token.

You can find a guide about it in the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad